# How can I delete javascript let variables using 'use strict'?

Tags: javascript, variables

I can delete variables without using let or var like this

```
y = 25;
delete y;
```

But I can't do it while using let. The variable is not deleted and I can console.log() it.

Comment: Why do you want to deleted variables?

Comment: like i want to delete it after using while loop

Comment: What do you mean by *"I can't do it while using let"*? `let` variables are block scoped. Why do you need to delete it?

Comment: WHY do you want to delete is after using while loop?

Comment: You still haven't said WHY you want to delete the variable.

Comment: .Please just answer my question

Comment: @AASog the answer is you cannot delete variables. And why people ask you an explanation because they want to help you to understand why you cannot do that and why you should not try to do that

Comment: @AASog You can read up on garbage collectors. You shouldn't need to worry about doing this

Comment: It does not matter. Automatic garbage collection will delete the variable from memory once it's not used anymore. Hence we keep asking: why does it matter that you manually delete a variable in a language with garbage collection?

Comment: @Olegi I knew that you can delete variables in python3 and though that I could delete it with js too so...

Answer (score 1):

the delete operator is used for removing properties from objects, not deleting variables.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

```
y = 25;
delete y;
```

is working because 'y' is a property of the window/global object not a variable

Comment: but I can't do this using 'use strict'

Comment: You are not allowed to do this in strict mode. You can read this article about it
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp

Comment: Objects whos properties get deleted cannot ( or couldn't ) be optimized the same way by V8 based browsers as objects that do not have properties deleted. Hence there are almost no cases where you would prefer `var obj = { x: 1 }; delete obj.x;` over `var obj = { x: 1}; obj.x = null;`.

Answer (score 0):

I knew the answer

```
{
   i = 0;
   while(i < 10){
       i++;
   }
   delete i;
}
```